# Reading into a txt file

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I'm very new to C and have the following issue. This program is supposed to read in exam scores from a data file and store the output into a text file. The output is supposed to be the number of grades as well as the number of each letter grade. 
Whenever I run it, it crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
FILE *inFile;
int current;
int sum = 0;
int b;
int theGrades[100];

inFile = fopen("a.txt", "r");

b = fscanf(inFile, "%d", &current); 

while(b != -1){
    theGrades[sum] = current;
    sum++;
    b = fscanf(inFile, "%d", &current);
}
fclose(inFile);

for(int i=0;i<=sum;i++){
    printf("%d" + theGrades[i]);
}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Check inFile (it must be valid pointer, not NULL) 
2) Check sum counter (must be < 100)
3) `printf("%d" + theGrades[i]);` - what are you doing? Have you `printf("%d",  theGrades[i]);` in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop needs help

```
for(int i=0;i<sum;i++){              //not <=
    printf("%d ", theGrades[i]);   // comma, not a plus sign
}
```

Also, check `fopen` for failure. Ensure you don't add more than 100 items. Use EOF instead of -1.